# How to fix Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts error

Tags: node.js, file-upload, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload file using nodejs express to google drive, Sending post request from postman, i got the error "Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts.", Problem is within the request body i think, Any idea would be grateful to solve this issue or any suggestions, thank you.

```
let file = req.files.form_doc_20;

var contentType = file.type || 'application/octet-stream';
let parentId = 'root';

const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

var data = fs.readFileSync(file.path);
let metadata = {
    title: file.name,
    mimeType: contentType,
    parents: [parentId]
};

var base64Data = Buffer(data, 'base64');

var multipartRequestBody =
    delimiter +
    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n" +
    JSON.stringify(metadata) +
    delimiter +
    "Content-Type: " + contentType + "\r\n" +
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    base64Data +
    close_delim;

let options = {
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files',
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': "multipart/related; boundary=\"" + boundary + "\"",
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + req.body.token_configuration.access_token,
    },
    body: multipartRequestBody,
    qs: {
        fields: "id, name, mimeType, modifiedTime, size",
        uploadType: 'multipart'
    },
    json: true
};

helper.http_request(options, (err1, response) => {
    if (err1) {
        return res.json({ msg: 'Failed to upload the file.', error: response });
    }
    else {
        return res.json({ result: response });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your script is almost correct and your script works by modifying the following 3 points.

### Modification points:

1. When you use Drive API v3, please use the property of `name` instead of `title`.
2. `base64Data` of the file can be retrieved by `new Buffer(data).toString('base64')`.
3. When `json: true` of `options` is used, the error of `Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts.` occurs. Please remove this.

### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

#### 1:

From:

```
title: file.name,
```

To:

```
name: file.name,
```

#### 2:

From:

```
var base64Data = Buffer(data, 'base64');
```

To:

```
var base64Data = new Buffer(data).toString('base64');
```

#### 3:

Please remove `json: true` from `options`.

### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your environment can upload files using Drive API. If the error related to API occurs, please confirm whether Drive API is enabled. And also please confirm the scopes including in the access token.
- I could confirm that the modified script can upload a file to Google Drive. So if other error occurs, it is considered that the other part which is not this script is the reason.

### References:

- [Uploading Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
- [Performing a Multipart Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/multipart-upload)

If these modifications were not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Usira I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Usira Do you have any idea to handle multiple file case ? I have multiple images to upload.

Comment: @SourabhBhutani, i think you have to upload one by one, there is no documentation for upload multiple files at once.

Comment: @Usira thanks for information. I think i have to append files array and to call https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media api for each file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using the following in the headers of the post request:

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="--subrequest_boundary"
```

But it should be

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="subrequest_boundary"
```

Also from [doc](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#http_1):

> Identify each part with a boundary string, preceded by 2 hyphens. In addition, **add 2 hyphens after the final boundary string.**

NB: hypen is -, so body should end with --